# How can I create a docker file for Excel that runs on Windows?

Tags: excel, docker, office365

```
FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN /bin/bash

ENTRYPOINT  python main.py
```

Comment: can you please clarify the intent of "for Excel" , what is it that you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I need open excel in a container Docker for block internet, the idea is run a script of python in my localhost for excel

Comment: Dockefile     



FROM python:3.8-slim-buster
COPY . /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
RUN /bin/bash

ENTRYPOINT  python main.py

Comment: Script Python
import os
os.system("start EXCEL.EXE")

Comment: well basically you want to encapsulate excel app and have it reside inside docker ? if you do this, data persistence will go away.

Comment: thanks! 
and how could I encapsulate excel correctly? would you have any recommendations?

Comment: just pull a ready made one, here: https://hub.docker.com/r/playniuniu/docker-excel, if this one is no good try searching for another one in docker hub. Why sit and create it when you can just pull one.